# FirstOrLast IObservable Extension

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to run through an `IObservable<T>` looking for an element that matches a predicate, and if not found, return the last element of the `IObservable<T>`.  I don't want to have to store the entire contents of the `IObservable<T>`, and I don't want to loop through the `IObservable` twice, so I've set up an extension method

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> FirstOrLastAsync<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> pred)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
        {
            var hot = source.Publish();
            var store = new AsyncSubject<T>();
            var d1 = hot.Subscribe(store);
            var d2 = hot.FirstAsync(x => pred(x)).Amb(store).Subscribe(o);
            var d3 = hot.Connect();
            return new CompositeDisposable(d1, d2, d3);
        });
    }

    public static T FirstOrLast<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> pred)
    {
        return source.FirstOrLastAsync(pred).Wait();
    }
}
```

The Async method creates a hot observable from a potentially cold one passed in.  It subscribes an `AsyncSubject<T>` to remember the last element, and an `IObservable<T>` that looks for the element.  It then takes the first element from either of those `IObservable<T>`s, which ever returns a value first via `.Amb` (`AsyncSubject<T>` doesn't return a value until it gets an `.OnCompleted` message).

My questions are the following:

- Can this be written better or more concisely using different Observable methods?
- Do all of those disposables need to be included in the CompositeDisposable?
- When the hot observable is completed without finding a matching element, is there a race condition between FirstAsync throwing an exception, and the AsyncSubject propagating its value?
- If so, do I need to change the line to:

`var d2 = hot.Where(x => pred(x)).Take(1).Amb(store).Subscribe(o);`

I'm pretty new to RX, and this is my first extension on IObservable.

*EDIT*

I ended up going with

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> FirstOrLastAsync<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> pred)
    {
        var hot = source.Publish().RefCount();
        return hot.TakeLast(1).Amb(hot.Where(pred).Take(1).Concat(Observable.Never<T>()));
    }

    public static T FirstOrLast<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> pred)
    {
        return source.FirstOrLastAsync(pred).First();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Amb the two cases you want together.
If your source observable is cold, you can do a `Publish|Refcount`.

```
    public static IObservable<T> FirstOrLast<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.TakeLast(1).Amb(source.Where(predicate).Take(1));
    }
```

Test:

```
        var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
                               .Take(10)
                               .Publish()
                               .RefCount();

        FirstOrLast(source, i => i == 5).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine); //5
        FirstOrLast(source, i => i == 11).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine); //9
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to return the last value when none of the values match the predicate.

Comment: @Enigmativity How so? Even if none of the values match, the TakeLast stream will still produce a value.

Comment: I'm getting a Sequence contains no elements exception when I try this, but this definitely qualifies as simpler if it works.

Comment: this works, but I'm not sure why the added bit is necessary.  `return Observable.Amb(source.Where(predicate).Take(1).Concat(Observable.Never<T>()), source.TakeLast(1));`

Comment: @MartinNeal This has probably to do with Amb reacting to notifications as opposed to values. It's only when the sequence completes that `TakeLast` is forwarded, so if a completion notification reaches Amb through the other stream, it probably disconnects. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Your tests and new code work unless you change `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)).Take(10)` to `Observable.Range(0, 10)` in which case I start getting that exception again.  Anyway to fix that?  Seems rx has many gotchas.

Comment: @Asti - When I tested your code it didn't work. It never produced a result. I assume that's changed now.

Comment: @MartinNeal Ah. `Observable.Range()` runs on the same thread - it's basically a for-loop calling `OnNext`, so the first subscription immediately runs to completion and will have published all the values before the second can even begin to subscribe.

Comment: @Enigmativity I tried this code first, but changed it to the `Observable.Amb` form because it was more readable. It seems there's actually a difference in the order of Amb's arguments. It could possibly be because the peculiarity of `TakeLast`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to produce a "simpler" query that works and so far nothing.

If I stick with your basic structure I can offer a slight improvement. Try this:

```
public static IObservable<T> FirstOrLastAsync<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> pred)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
    {
        var hot = source.Publish();
        var store = new AsyncSubject<T>();
        var d1 = hot.Subscribe(store);
        var d2 =
            hot
                .Where(x => pred(x))
                .Concat(store)
                .Take(1)
                .Subscribe(o);
        var d3 = hot.Connect();
        return new CompositeDisposable(d1, d2, d3);
    });
}
```

It's not hugely better, but I like it better than using `Amb`. It's just a tad cleaner I think.